# How to run a command when atom starts

Tags: command, startup, atom-editor

I would like to run various commands when Atom starts, so that it opens in the state I expect it to without having to run those commands manually every time.

I know `init.coffee` is run when Atom starts, but I don't know how to run a command from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/call-atom-command-from-package/7465):

`atom.commands.dispatch(atom.views.getView(atom.workspace), 'package:command');`

Just change `package:command` to your desired package & command, and put the result in your `init.coffee`.

`package:command` is the same syntax you would use in `keymap.cson`. Basically, it's the name of the package and the name of the command you can find in the command palette, but lowercased and using dashes instead of spaces. ex: `Fuzzy Finder: Toggle File Finder` becomes `fuzzy-finder:toggle-file-finder`

`atom.views.getView(atom.workspace)` is to dispatch the command into the full workspace. If you want to target the current text editor instead, try `atom.views.getView(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor())`.

You can test the whole thing by running it in the Dev Tools Console (open it using `Window: Toggle Dev Tools`, or `Ctrl+Shift+I`, or `F12`).

```
> atom.commands.dispatch(atom.views.getView(atom.workspace), 'fuzzy-finder:toggle-file-finder');
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: Array(1)}
```

Comment: Where to put this? I tried to put it inside `init.coffee` but I am getting this error: `Failed to load C:\Users\User\.atom\init.coffee
Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null`

Comment: @W.M. Which `'package:command'` are you trying to run? I suspect it is causing the issue. I added instructions on how to test it in the Dev Tools Console. Maybe the command you're trying to run does't work on the `atom.workspace` view - in which case you would need to identify the proper view to use.

Comment: `fuzzy-finder:toggle-file-finder` worked for me.
But when I try:
`atom.commands.dispatch(atom.views.getView(atom.workspace), "hydrogen-python:toggle-variable-explorer");`
it didn't work... any thought?

Comment: @WestYang I have never used that package, but I think it need to target a specific file you're working in, rather than the entire workspace. Try `atom.views.getView(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor())` instead.