# How to add custom command from package in Atom.io?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm having difficulties to add custom command in Atom editor. Tried to search here, but I think it worked on previous version but not in the latest version (1.34). Since there is no sample in the documentation. Please help my case:

Basically, I want to trigger "core:select-all" and "join-plus:join-csv-single-quote" in 1 key. So in order to achieve that, I saw that I can use dispatch command.

Some other article that I found:

[How do I write a custom command in Atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456995/how-do-i-write-a-custom-command-in-atom)

[How to run a command when atom starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645238/how-to-run-a-command-when-atom-starts)

https://blog.atom.io/2018/10/09/automate-repetitive-tasks-with-composed-commands.html

I tried to implement things based on my findings, but none of them are working. Did I do correctly ?

PS: I tried step by step, so i found it is not even working on first step (core:select-all)

My init.coffee

```
atom.commands.add 'custom-command',
'custom:command': ->
view = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor())
atom.commands.dispatch(view, "core:select-all")
```

My keymap.cson

```
'atom-workspace':
'alt-shift-o': 'custom-command'
```

Below is my atom screenshot to make sure the keybindings setting:

[image: My atom configuration]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456995/how-do-i-write-a-custom-command-in-atom

Comment: @AbdullaThanseeh, I did mention that SO. It worked but my problem is actually with the command from package, so pls help to explain how to put the command in that code ?  because I believe I should do "dispatch" command ?

Comment: Is the code in your `init.coffee` properly indented? Does Atom show any errors in the Developer Tools console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Atom documentation](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.34.0/CommandRegistry#instance-add):

> `::add(target, commandName, listener)`
>
> Add one or more command listeners associated with a selector.

Your first argument for that method is not the target, but a custom string. The following works fine:

```
atom.commands.add "atom-workspace", "custom-command": ->
    view = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor())

    atom.commands.dispatch(view, "core:select-all")
    atom.commands.dispatch(view, "join-plus:join-csv-single-quote")
```

You might have to restart Atom before the changes in your `init.coffee` take effect.

Also note that CoffeeScript is a indentation-sensitive language. The code you have posted should have created an error in Atom. If you feel more comfortable with JavaScript, you can replace your `init.coffee` with `init.js` and convert the above code with [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee/) or [decaffeinate](https://decaffeinate-project.org/repl/).

Comment: Thanks !! I was aware about the indention and there was no error from atom.